# ggplot2 - Change `geom_rect` colour in a stacked barplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a stacked barplot using `ggplot2::geom_bar` with backgroud shading (using `ggplot2::geom_rect()`) according to a categorical variable as follows:

```
shading <- data.frame(min = seq(from = 0.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(diamonds$clarity))), by = 1),
                      max = seq(from = 1.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(diamonds$clarity))) + 0.5, by = 1),
                      col = c(0,1))

ggplot() + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")) +
  geom_bar(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(clarity, fill=cut)) +
  geom_rect(data = shading,
            aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                fill = factor(col), alpha = 0.1)) +
  geom_bar(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(clarity, fill=cut)) +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

[image]

How to change the colours of the shading? 
I have tried `scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "gray53"))`, but it seems that multiple scale aesthetics are not possible in `ggplot2` (https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/578). Is there another way to get the desired result ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, instead of putting your colours in the `aes()`, put them outside (so they are used as-is). Since it's outside the `aes()` call you will have to use an explicit `fill=shading$col` rather than `fill=col`, and `shading$col` should have the colour name you are after (rather than a variable interpreted as a factor).

```
shading$col <- ifelse(shading$col, 'white', 'gray53')
ggplot() + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")) +
  geom_bar(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(clarity, fill=cut)) +
  geom_rect(data = shading,
            aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.1),
                fill=shading$col) + # <-- here
  geom_bar(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(clarity, fill=cut)) +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```